# i have a form application as a dll and i want to run it in my console application. how do i do that

Tags: c#, forms, console, console-application

i have a console application and i would like to run the code from this Dll with it:

this is the code for the Dll:

```
namespace shutdown_msg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

this is my console application code that should "run" the Dll

```
  if (txt.IndexOf("shutdown") >= 0)
            {

            Console.WriteLine("shutdown was said");
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new shutdown_msg.Form1());

            }
```

Comment: This question makes very little sense. What is the purpose of defining this form in a DLL? And what is wrong with the code you've shown?

Comment: the problem with the code i've shown is that it gives an error saying "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't run a `dll`, you reference it only. You can run an `exe`.

You have 2 options:

**1- Generate an executable:**

You can build your windows forms application, then you can get the 'exe' out of the projects folders. Then you can Run it inside your console application using

```
Process.Start("yourPathHere.exe");
```

**2- Generate a dll:**

In Winforms project Go to Project => Right Click => Properties > Output Type => Class Library.

In Console App:
Right click on References => Add Reference => Browse to your dll path.

and add a Reference also for `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Then from Console App:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var f = new WindowsFormsProjectName.Form1();
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

OR:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new WindowsFormsProjectName.Form1());
}
```

Comment: yea that's what i meant can you please explain how i do this. i already referenced it in my console application

Comment: i am getting an error saying "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)" i used the Dll method

Comment: @IDKanything are you trying to debug the code inside the dll from the console app ?

Comment: @IDKanything You code works completely fine for me (It did shutdown my pc). Be aware that every time you change the windows form project code, you need to rebuild the solution to generate a new copy of the dll file.

Comment: my code is prefectly fine the problem is the code to make it work isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Run(new shutdown_msg.Form1());
```

Just run your form directly.

You can find the same code in `Program.cs` in any normal WinForm project.

Comment: when i added this line i start my script everything is fine but when i say any command it breaks "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)"

Comment: it dosent work look at the comment my other comment on this answer